# creating timestamp column using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I'd love to create a new timestamp column on a dataframe using a date column and a string column

| Date | Times (Sting) | desired column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-03 | 15:34:02 | 2020-11-03 15:34:02 |

i'm trying something like that in the select statement but i'm having an error. Can anyone help?

```
F.to_timestamp(F.concat_ws('', F.col("Date"), F.col("Time"), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')).alias("desired_column")
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: there should be a space (`' '`) between date and time, based on your ts format provided to `to_timestamp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do something like this by using `pyspark` [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/functions.html):

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf

sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlc = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)

# note this i used to create the data frame
df = sqlc.createDataFrame([('2020-11-03','15:34:02')], ['Date', 'Times (Sting)'])

print(df.show())

df = df.withColumn('desired column',sf.concat(sf.col('Date'),sf.lit(' '), sf.col('Times (Sting)')))

print(df.show())
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: yes easy and worked! thanks

Comment: it's returning string format, how can i cast it to timestamp?

Comment: @f.ivy glad it worked. you can use to_timestamp method to cast it to timestamp: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp.html

Answer (score 0):

Use **`to_timestamp()`** function as it returns `timestamp` type.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2020-11-03','15:34:02')], ['Date', 'Times (Sting)'])
df.withColumn('desired column',to_timestamp(concat(col('Date'),lit(' '), col('Times (Sting)')))).show(10,False)
df.withColumn('desired column',to_timestamp(concat(col('Date'),lit(' '), col('Times (Sting)')))).printSchema()

#+----------+-------------+-------------------+
#|Date      |Times (Sting)|desired column     |
#+----------+-------------+-------------------+
#|2020-11-03|15:34:02     |2020-11-03 15:34:02|
#+----------+-------------+-------------------+
#
#root
# |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
# |-- Times (Sting): string (nullable = true)
# |-- desired column: timestamp (nullable = true)
```